# link btn re-direct holding session variable

Tags: asp.net, linq, linkbutton

I want to use a link button to run a function 'LoadCheckListRecordEntry' which sets a session and re directs the user...However the page seems to be loading be the session is set??

ALthough the html is running the code b4 the 'DiaryEntId' actually gets set, so it returns null in the LINQ...How can i resolve this?

Comment: `However the page seems to be loading be the session is set??` means

Comment: you know the way functions are loaded in a certai order etc...page init, page load etc....well this loads LoadCheckListRecordEntry first, before the DiaryEntId is set